# In Excel/VBA, how to apply a formula to a range based on cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data (S8:S999) that contains various units of measure (PC, CTN, EA, etc).
The column to the right (T8:T999) contains a location.

I'd like to apply a formula to cells in the adjacent cells (T8:T999), but only where the value in (S8:S999) contains the "PC" value. We have items with multiple UOM, and for example the CTN and PC variations have different locations. Our report is limited, and only generates the primary/CTN location. This button/script will change the locations of any items listed as PC (but not CTN, etc)

So if "S8" is "PC", apply formula to "T8"

if "S27" is "PC", apply formula to "T27" etc

Updated code (thanks BigBen)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim UomRange As Range

  Set UomRange = Worksheets("START").Range("S8:S999")
  
  For Each cell In UomRange
    If cell.Value Like "PC" Then
    cell.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(J8,LocRef!$A$1:$C$9999,3,FALSE)"
        
    Else
  
  
  End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks very odd. You are applying different formulas to the same range over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do looks very weird, but anyways...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim UomRange As Range

Dim Dummy As Integer
Set UomRange = Worksheets("START").Range("S8:S999")

For Each cell In UomRange
    if cell.HasFormula = False then  'Has  no formula, so could be "PC"
        If cell.Value Like "PC" Then
            Range("S8:S999").Formula = "=MyFormulaHere"
        end if
    'else 'If it has a formula, it by definition won't look like the text "PC" (unless you've if logic in your formula?) so we can bypass
    end if  
Next

End Sub
```

But I suspect you are not looking to do what you have presented so far...

edit:

If UoMRange is supposed to represent the item number which can drive the change in location - which occurs via formula then the definition of UoMRange in your original isn't right.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. 

Three columns of data, "Item number " "Unit of measure" and "Location" 

The location is dynamic, and a formula is used to change the location based on the item number. I only want the formula applied to the location if the UOM is "PC"

Comment: Probably want `Offset`: `If cell.Value = "PC" Then cell.Offset(,1).Formula = "MyFormulaHere"`.

Comment: What confuses me the most is that OP is overwriting the range they're reading.

Comment: BigBen may have nailed it, my apologies for my terrible example (I was trying to simplify my issue)

Comment: I updated the original question to make more sense for others.